# Split large matrix to smaller ones

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a `15276x30991` matrix and I would like to split it to `3` smaller matrices i know that I have to use `mat2cell` function but I cannot manage to set the dimensions correctly. Could you please help me on how can i achieve this?

Example For a matrix `300x25` to split in to `10` matrices of `30x25` dimensions should be

```
Mcell = mat2cell(A,repmat(30,10,1),25)
```

Comment: When you say 3 smaller matrices what sizes do you want the new matrices to be?

Comment: I would prefer to be 16x31

Comment: How would that make it _three_ smaller matrices? Please update the question to be clearer on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Ok sorry,as my matrix is a large one I would like to make this  large matrix as small as possible.So to split it in smaller ones is a solution for memory problems as I am trying to make an assosiative memory(neural network).

Comment: @Konstantinos: do you mean you want to split it along the rows into three matrices?

Comment: @Amro yes something like that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split the matrix along the rows into three matrices, try:

```
>> x = rand(15276,100);
>> C = mat2cell(x, ones(3,1)*(size(x,1)/3), size(x,2))
C = 
    [5092x100 double]
    [5092x100 double]
    [5092x100 double]
```

This assumes that `size(x,1)` is evenly divisible by 3, which is true in your case: `15276/3 = 5092`