# Split a matrix into smaller matrices with cell arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, split

There are several questions on how to split a large matrix into smaller matrices and they all suggest `mat2cell`.

For example, here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684105/split-a-matrix-into-smaller-matrices) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366015/split-large-matrix-to-smaller-ones).

I tried, but I get a cell array that I have to reconvert into a matrix, as I tried to answer in the first question (I deleted the answer).

I tested this:

```
e = magic(20);

tic
f = mat2cell( e, 20, [10 10] );
f1 = cell2mat(f(1,1));
f2 =cell2mat(f(1,2));
toc

tic
f1 = e(:,1:10);
f2 = e(:,11:20);
toc
```

And I get

```
Elapsed time is 0.000437 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.000009 seconds.
```

The difference is large, when in relation to one another. 
What's the advantage of solving this problem with cell arrays?

Comment: Your question is not consistent with the title. Also, the real question `What's the advantage of cell arrays?` is kind of opionion-based -> off topic. Try to re-formulate the question so that it can be answered in a distinct way rather than a discussion.

Comment: The key here is that you don't want to create the variables ``f1`` and ``f2`` but rather only a cell-variable ``f``. That way ``f1`` becomes ``f{1}`` and ``f2`` becomes ``f{2}``, where the index of those matrices can really be used as an index (i.e. for looping over them). This get's worse and worse if you don't split into two submatrices, but rather into 20 or 200. Nobody wants to deal with variables ``f1`` to ``f200``, but rather use ``f{1}`` to ``f{200}``.

Comment: But then I'd have to convert them anyway to use them?
@kkuilla I'll try, but I really want to know from somebody that is more expert than me why. I know it is not an actual "help me with code" question.

Comment: @rickratti Did you try? ``f1 + f{2}`` should give exactly the same as ``f1+f2`` and ``f{1} + f{2}`` and ``f{1} + f2``. Nothing has to be converted. They are perfectly substitutable, hence you do not need the variables ``f1`` and ``f2``.

Comment: Not sure what I was doing wrong then, probably I wasn't using `{}`.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably... But this is a good question to emphasize the concept: try not to hide indices in variable names, but use a "real" index instead. Consider 2 row vectors ``v1`` and ``v2``. They could be set up into a matrix ``v`` and adressed by ``v(1,:)`` and ``v(2,:)``  (if they are of the same size) or into a cell and then be adressed by ``v{1}``, ``v{2}``. Therefore goes your +1 :-).

Comment: I tend to use different names to know exactly what they represent, but that's always good advice and I'll see if I can actually apply it somewhere in my code. Thank you! Your comments actually explained the whole situation perfectly. If you write the answer  to the question I'll reciprocate :)